# Get all orders between specific date shown in order of months

Tags: php, sql, loops, sorting, date

I have a table with coupon codes that have a timestamp from when they were created.

The basics of that table look like this:

```
`coupon_codes`
- coupon_id
- timestamp
- account_id
```

Then there is an order table that has a row called `coupon_id` so I can see when an order was placed, a particular coupon code was used. This table looks like this:

```
`orders`
- order_id
- timestamp
- account_id
- coupon_id
```

Now I would like to display all orders that were placed from the creation (timestamp) with a specific coupon code. And group them per year and per month. Like this:

```
2021
- Jan
-- Order
-- Order
-- Order
- Feb
-- Order
- Mar
-- Order

2020
- Jan
-- Order
-- Order
-- Order
- Feb
- Mar
-- Order
-- Order
-- Order

Etc
```

How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
<?PHP
$getkortingstartdate = '
SELECT * FROM coupon_codes WHERE account_id = "'.$conn->real_escape_string($_GET['account_id']).'"';
$getkortingstartdatecon = $conn->query($getkortingstartdate);
$getkortingstartdate = $getkortingstartdatecon->fetch_assoc();
$date1 = strtotime($getkortingstartdate['timestamp']);
$date2 = strtotime('today');

while ($date1 <= $date2) {
  $years = date('Y', $date1) . "<br>";
  echo $years;
  echo date('Y-m', $date1) . "<br>";
  $date1 = strtotime('+1 month', $date1);
  $months = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Okt","Nov","Dec");
  foreach ($months as $month) {
    $maand = date('m',strtotime($month));
    $monthandyear = $maand."-".$years;
    echo $monthandyear;
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Start using prepared statements, as now you're wide open to SQL Injections 2) Research the proper use of [`fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) in a loop. 3) Use [`ORDER BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/) in your query to sort by timestamp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select all the orders like that:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE coupon_id IN (SELECT coupon_id FROM coupon_codes WHERE account_id = "XXX")
ORDER BY timestamp
```

(escape the *account_id* parameter as mentioned in the comments)

So this way it should be already sorted by the order date. Then you can iterate through the result and output year and month based on the row's timestamp followed by the order data.